# Battery stats over USB-PD

Tags: usb

I have a USB-PD question. I am working on a project that will use USB-PD (via USB-C connector) to charger devices, for example a laptop, tablet, mobile phone, etc. Think if this as a "Shared Capacity Charger" where the total available power is being distributed between a few devices. There is another team that will be coming on board that will be responsible for the USB-PD HW and protocol implementation, but they are not available yet, hense the question here.

So the question: Over the typical USB-PD protocol, is there information available about the device being charged such as a UUID of the device, battery capacity of the device, current % charged (with periodic update during charging), number of charging cycles, etc.

I would like to keep history of devices charged and, when charging, their current charge level. This would then be provided to the user. I just don't know if this type of data part of the USB-PD protocol (and typically implemented if optional), or if we would need to implement an app to run on the devices being charged to provide the information by other means outside of the usb-pd protocol?

Any help in understanding the typical information about the power sink device normally available in the USB-PD protocol would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

USBPD 3.0 protocol allows you to query the battery charge.
For example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBZst.png)

Unfortunately, manufacturers of Power Banks with Power Delivery software set the type to this device as a power supply (but not a battery), so the Power Bank itself considers that it is a power supply and cannot give Charge Status.

Here is example:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnFyI.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWth0.png)

Here is the reason:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDPcC.png)